# Rebuilding huffman tree with character locations

Tags: java, stringbuilder, huffman-code, stringbuffer

I am trying to rebuild a Huffman tree from a map of chars and strings (char locations on the tree). I am iterating through the map and passing it the string and the char each time.

It works fine for small texts but starts to slow down after about 500 lines.

I am wondering if the problem lies with the StringBuffer or somewhere else, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
private void decode(HuffmanNode root, StringBuffer code, Character theChar) {
    if (code.length() > 1) {
        if (code.charAt(0) == '0') {
            if (root.getLeft() == null) {
                root.setLeft(new HuffmanNode('\0', 0, null, null));
                decode(root.getLeft(), code.deleteCharAt(0), theChar);
            } else {
                decode(root.getLeft(), code.deleteCharAt(0), theChar);

            }
        } else {
            if (root.getRight() == null) {
                root.setRight(new HuffmanNode('\0', 0, null, null));
                decode(root.getRight(), code.deleteCharAt(0), theChar);
            } else {
                decode(root.getRight(), code.deleteCharAt(0), theChar);
            }
        }
    }

    if (code.length() == 1) {
        if (code.charAt(0) == '0') {
            if (root.getLeft() == null) {
                root.setLeft(new HuffmanNode(theChar, 0, null, null));
            } else {
                root.getLeft().setChar(theChar);
            }
        } else {
            if (root.getRight() == null) {
                root.setRight(new HuffmanNode(theChar, 0, null, null));
            } else {
                root.getRight().setChar(theChar);
            }
        }
        code.deleteCharAt(0);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Seems like tree grows , so I think thats just the Big O.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I believe that deleteCharAt is linear time, anyway to reduce that down to constant time?

Comment: I need a fast way to delete the first element (char) in a string.

Comment: The character removal isn't the issue. I used a queue and it is still slow.